# Differentiable function satisfying $f(x+a) = bf(x)$ for all $x$

Tags: calculus, functional-equations

This is an exercise from Apostol *Calculus*, (Exercise 10 on page 269).

> What can you conclude about a function which has derivative everywhere and satisfies an equation of the form
>   $$ f(x+a) = bf(x) $$
>   for all $x$, where $a$ and $b$ are positive constants?

The answer in the back of the book suggests that we should conclude $f(x) = b^{x/a} g(x)$ where $g(x)$ is a periodic function with period $a$.  I'm not sure how to arrive at this.

One initial step is to say, by induction,
$$ f(x+a) = bf(x) \implies f(x+na) = b^n f(x)$$
for all $x$.  I'm not sure what to do with this though.  I'm also not clear how to use the differentiability of $f$.  (If I write down the limit definition of the derivative then I end up with a term $f(x+h)$, but I cannot use the functional equation on that since the functional equation is for a fixed constant $a$.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One trivial solution that doesn't use the differentiability of $ f(x) $:

From $ f(x+na)=b^nf(x) $, letting $ y=x+na $, and requiring that $ x \in [0,a) $ and $ n = \left\lfloor \frac{y}{a} \right\rfloor $ we get the following equivalent definition of $ f $:

$$ f(y)=b^{\frac{y-\left(y-\left\lfloor \frac{y}{a} \right\rfloor a\right)}{a}}f\left (y- \left\lfloor \frac{y}{a} \right\rfloor a \right) $$

By letting $ g(y)=b^{-\frac{\left( y-\left\lfloor \frac{y}{a} \right\rfloor a\right)}{a}}f\left(y-\left\lfloor \frac{y}{a} \right\rfloor a \right) $ noting that $ g $ is periodic with a period of $ a $:

$$ f(y)=b^{\frac{y}{a}}g(y) $$

Answer (score 3):

$$f(x+a)=bf(x)$$

$$f'(x+a)=bf'(x)$$

Then

$$\frac{f'(x+a)}{f(x+a)}=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$

Let

$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=h(x)$$

$$f(x)=\exp\left(\int{h(x)}{dx}\right)$$

And we require :

$$h(x+a):=h(x)$$

Now from $f(x+a)=bf(x)$ :

$$\exp\left(\int^{x+a}{h(x)}{dx}\right)=b \,\, \exp\left(\int^x{h(x)}{dx}\right)$$

$$\exp\left(\int^{x+a}_x{h(x)}{dx}\right)=b$$

Now your book suggests $f(x)=b^\frac{x}{a}g(x)=e^{\frac{x \ln b}{a}}g(x)$

This gets :

$$f'(x)=\frac{\ln b}{a}e^{\frac{x \ln b}{a}}g(x)+e^{\frac{x \ln b}{a}}g'(x)$$

$$h(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{\ln b}{a}+\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}$$

As $g(x)$ and $g'(x)$ are both periodic we can see that this makes $h(x)$ periodic as well.  So the form we derived earlier is simply related to the form the book describes.

And equating $\frac{f'(x+a)}{f(x+a)}=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ we get

$$\frac{g'(x+a)}{g(x+a)}=\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}$$

Which is correct if $g(x)$ has a period $a$.

Comment: I don't understand what you've done in the equations following "Now from $f(x+a) = bf(x)$.  Should those bounds of integration be in a different variable from the variable we are integrating over?  Also, this just seems circular since if I take the $\log$ of both sides and then integrate we end up write where we started: $f(x+a) = bf(x)$.

Comment: It makes no difference what variable we use for the integration, as in this case it is simply a label.  We could use $t$ or $\theta$ on one side instead of $x$ but we get the same "shape" of function as a result of integration, and evaluate that at either $x$ or $x+a$.  I am afraid I do not know what you mean by "taking the log of both sides and integrate".  What equation ?  The art in mathematics is often knowing which path or operation to do to avoid ending up where you came from.

Comment: Ok, so the $x$ you are integrating against is a different $x$ than the the one on the bounds of integration?  Which is fine, I just want to be clear.  What I mean is that you've just rearranged some terms.  I don't see where we have derived an expression for $f(x)$ until the end where we assume that it is of the form given in the back of the book.  The expression $$\exp \left( \int_x^{x+a} h(x) \, dx \right) = b$$ is just a different way of writing $f(x+a) = bf(x)$.  We haven't gotten an expression for $f(x)$ in terms of a periodic function $g(x)$.

Comment: I think you may be writing the MathJax in comments using double dollar signs, because it doesn't show up until I edit.  I think comments only use single dollar ( inline ) forms of MathJax.  In fact both the book and my answer cannot do more than derive a "shape" for the function $f(x)$ and the shape in the book is just a "transformation" of the one I gave.  The form in the back of the book, as I tried to show you, is just a different arrangement of the one I derived.  Regarding the use of variables, think of them as *symbols*, and not variables and it may help.

Comment: I can see display math in comments without issue (on this post and others).  My point on the variable $x$ is that you have written $\int_x^{x+a} h(x) \, dx$ but the $x$ in the limits of integration is representing something different than the $x$ in $h(x) \, dx$.  Maybe $\int_x^{x+a} h(t) \, dt$ would be more clear if that is what you mean?

Comment: Yes, if you find the $t$ form clearer then fine.  The integral means the same thing in both cases.

Comment: I do not thing $\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} h(x) \,dx$ is in general the same thing as $\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} h(t) \, dt$.  For instance, try differentiating these two.  You'd need to use the Leibniz rule on the first and would get something involving $a'(x)$ and $b'(x)$.  (Maybe in this case it turns out not to matter since $a(x) = x$ and $b(x) = x+a$ implies $a'(x) = 1$ and $b'(x) = 1$.)

Comment: No they are the same.  You need to think of the integral without the limits first.  So the integral is $s(t):=\int{f(t)}{dt}$.  Now the *definite* integral is simply $\int_x^{x+a}{f(t)}{dt}=s(x+a)-s(x)$.  It makes no difference what symbol we use inside the definite integral, as we will be replacing that with the limits when we are finished.  The $x$ inside the definite integral is gone and replaced by the limits.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine While the beginning seemed promising, it is not even clear what the point in the answer is. One obvious mistake is that, ∫h(x)dx=log|f(x)|+C, because nobody said f(x) is non-negative, as exp(x) is, so it is incorrect that f(x)=exp(∫h(x)). Furthermore, we do not know that g(x) is continuous, because it is said that f′(x) exists, but not that it is also continuous. Can you please make the point in your answer, such that it does not start with a solution and prove that the solution is correct, because that is already known?

Answer (score 0):

The function $g$ defined by $g(x9=b^{-x/a}f(x)$ clearly satisfies $g(x+a)=g(x)$, hence the periodicity. The given differentiality is not used, except that you *may* use it to conclude that $g$ is differentiable.

Comment: This just verifies that the given answer is correct, but doesn't indicate how one might arrive at that answer, other than looking in the back of the book.

Comment: @user2718281828 The $g$ is a deus ex macjina here, but from a pattern one should recognize even while asleep ... The way $g$ is introduced in the accepted answer doesn't seem a lot more motiveted to me.